How to publish an event when NATS client connects or disconnects?
I am using NATS WebSocket in a JavaScript web browser application and I would like to have a way of knowing when a new client is connected or an existing is disconnected.
I was thinking of publishing a message to a specific subject when these events happen, but I cannot find a way to configure NATS server to do that.
Is it possible to achieve with NATS or is there some other approach that would tell connected clients that other client is connected or disconnected?

I solved this by using $SYS.ACCOUNT.*.DISCONNECT and $SYS.ACCOUNT.*.CONNECT subjects. I created a SYS user that is subscribed to these subjects. When a message is published here, it takes that message and republishes it to another subject that is available to regular users.
